# Misaligned vertical line in tabular environment

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have an issue with a nested table.
[image: misaligned vertical line in table]

The vertical double line on the right of this table is in the wrong position.
Here's my code:

```
\begin{center}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{||c||}
        \hline
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth-2em}{c|c|X|X}
            Nr./ID  & 1 & Nichttechnischer Titel    & Test 1 \\
        \end{tabularx}
        \\
        \hline
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth-2em}{c|X|c|c|X}
            Quelle  & State Manager Tests  & Version 1.0   & Test bestanden?       & \checkmark \\
        \end{tabularx}
        \\
        \hline
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth-2em}{c|X}
            Beschreibung    &  \\
        \end{tabularx}
        \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular*}
\end{center}
```

What causes this, and how can I fix this issue?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please, always give a complete example. Don't make people guess what packages etc. they need.`\checkmark` is an unknown command.

Comment: I think your inner `tabularx`es are too wide with respect to the outer `tabular*`.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum I'm sorry, the packages used are `tabularx` and `amssyb`for the checkmark. 
I assume that too, but I don't know what length I could use instead of `\linewidth` or `\columnwidth`, which both produce the same result.

Comment: Also is missing  the `calc` package  to use `\linewidth-2em`  without `\dimexpr`. BTW, you substract  2 \tabcolsep to each nested table, but not the widths of the vertical lines.

Comment: Why some may `\tabular` and `\tabularx`? You certainly don't need them!

Answer (score 1):

Your `tabular*` is not going to work. The `c` column is just that: it centers its contents, but its width will not stretch. I think it only works if you put stretchable space between the columns, but that requires at least two columns.

So better use also a `tabularx` for the outer one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{||X||}
        \hline
        {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth-2em}{c|c|X|X}
            Nr./ID  & 1 & Nichttechnischer Titel    & Test 1 \\
        \end{tabularx}}
        \\
        \hline
        {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth-2em}{c|X|c|c|X}
          Quelle  & State Manager Tests  & Version 1.0   & Test bestanden?       & \checkmark \\
        \end{tabularx}}
        \\
        \hline
        {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth-2em}{c|X}
            Beschreibung    &  \\
        \end{tabularx}}
        \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know you could use {} to get a tabularx inside a tabularx, and was using the tabular* because of that.